# Get response / event handle after FB.Share

Tags: php, facebook, fbml, fbconnect

in my php code im using below code to share data :

```
    <a id="fbshare" class="fbshare" href="#" onclick="fbshare()" name="fb_share" share_url="<?=$dataLink"></a>
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

i want response/event back to the page.

any help appreciable .. !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
    FB.ui(
   {
     method: 'feed',
     name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
     link: 'http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
     picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
     caption: 'Reference Documentation',
     description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.',
     message: 'Facebook Dialogs are easy!'
   },
   function(response) {
     if (response && response.post_id) {
       alert('Post was published.');
     } else {
       alert('Post was not published.');
     }
   }
 );
```

I suppose you are calling FB.ui method in your  fbshare function, you can add there a function to get response, here is an example code.